# gorm: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, go-gorm

I get the following error: `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 23 [running]`.

If I remove `config.NewConfig().Repo.InsertLicense(license)` in this function I don't get an error. That means this line causes the error in this function

```
func generateAvailableLicenses() {
license := entity.License{
    Key:         generateRandomLicenseKey(),
    IsUsed:      entity.AVAILABLE,
    CreatedAt:   time.Now().Format("2006-01-02"),
    ExpiresAt:   time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, 1).Format("2006-01-02"),
    CompanyId:   "1",
    CompanyName: "Company 1",
    TeamId:      "1",
    TeamName:    "Team 1",
}
availableLicenses = append(availableLicenses, license)

config.NewConfig().Repo.InsertLicense(license) // error line
}
```

That's everything for my config:

```golang
type Config struct {
    WebPort string
    Repo    repository.Repository
}

func NewConfig() *Config {
    return &Config{
        WebPort: ":8080",
    }
}

func (app *Config) SetupPostgresRepository(conn *gorm.DB) {
    db := postgres.NewPostgresRepository(conn)
    app.Repo = db
}
```

Repository

```golang
type PostgresRepository struct {
    Conn *gorm.DB
}

var db *gorm.DB 

func NewPostgresRepository(pool *gorm.DB) *PostgresRepository {
    db = pool
    return &PostgresRepository{
        Conn: pool,
    }
}

func (u *PostgresRepository) InsertLicense(license entity.License) error {
    result := db.Create(&license)
    if result.Error != nil {
        return result.Error
    }
    return nil
}
```

Tech: Go, gorm, Postgresql, docker

Comment: when returning `NewConfig()`, `Repo` of type `repository.Repository` is not initialized.

Comment: `InsertLicense` uses global `db` variable in it which is initialised in `NewPostgresRepository`. So `NewPostgresRepository` hasn't been called here.

Answer (score 0):

This could potentially trying to access a value which is still not yet initialised.

Makes sure to initialise and fill all repository values before using it.

you can use `func init()` if application architecture allows.